# Завершить выполнение функции

Tags: javascript

Нужно, что бы в else, `mousemove` не выполнялся:

```
$('#modalImg').click(function() {
  $('.modalImg').toggleClass('loop');
  if ($('.modalImg').hasClass('loop')) {
    $('#modalImgs').on("mousemove", function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      TranY = e.clientY / 4;
      TranRes = "scale(2) " + "translateY(" + ~TranY + "px)";
      $('.modalImg').css('transform', TranRes);
    });

  } else {
    $('#modalNext, #modalPrev').fadeIn(250);
    $('.modalImg').css('transform', 'scale(1)');
  }
});
```

Comment: так? else {  $('#modalImgs').on("mousemove", function () {}) }

Comment: сейчас подправлю

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.on()` включает, `.off()` отключает))

```js
$('#modalImg').click(function() {
  $('.modalImg').toggleClass('loop');
  if ($('.modalImg').hasClass('loop')) {
    $('#modalImgs').on("mousemove", function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      TranY = e.clientY / 4;
      TranRes = "scale(2) " + "translateY(" + ~TranY + "px)";
      $('.modalImg').css('transform', TranRes);
    });

  } else {
    $('#modalNext, #modalPrev').fadeIn(250);
    $('.modalImg').css('transform', 'scale(1)');    
    $('#modalImgs').off("mousemove"); // <---
  }
});
```

```css
#modalNext, .modalImg { width: 50px; height: 50px; border: 1px solid red; }

.loop {background: #ddd;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="modalNext">test</div>

<div id="modalImgs">
  <div id="modalImg">
    <div class="modalImg">Click</div>
  </div>
</div>
```